# C# Methods in console Based

Tags: c#

I having difficulty running my program that contains several methods within the same class. Here is the code:

```
namespace E03_pt2_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfDrawers = 0;
            string deskWoodType = "o";
            double cost = 0;
            drawersMeth(out numberOfDrawers);
            woodTypeMeth(out deskWoodType);
            CalculateCostMeth(ref numberOfDrawers, ref cost, ref deskWoodType);
            OutPutCostMeth(ref deskWoodType , cost, numberOfDrawers);
        }//end main

        private static void drawersMeth(out int numberOfDrawers)
        {
            int numOfDrawers;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of desk drawers");
            numOfDrawers = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            numberOfDrawers = numOfDrawers;
        }//end drawersMeth

        private static string woodTypeMeth(out string deskWoodType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the desk wood type. (ex. type mahogany, oak, or pine)");
            deskWoodType = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (deskWoodType)
            {
                case "mahogany":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "m";
                        break;
                    }
                case "oak":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "o";
                        break;
                    }
                case "pine":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "p";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "error";
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return deskWoodType;
        }// end woodTypeMeth

        private static int CalculateCostMeth(ref string deskWoodType, ref int numberOfDrawers, out int cost)
        {
            int pine = 100;
            int oak = 140;
            int other = 180;
            int surchage = 30;
            if (deskWoodType == "p")
                cost = pine + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            else if (deskWoodType == "o")
                cost = oak + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            else
                cost = other + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            return cost;
        }// end CalculateCostMeth

        private static void OutPutCostMeth(int numberOfDrawers, string deskWoodType, int cost)
        {
            double totalCost = cost;
            Console.WriteLine("The number of drawers is {0}", numberOfDrawers);
            Console.WriteLine("The wood finish you have selected is ", deskWoodType);
            Console.WriteLine("The total cost is {0}", totalCost);
        }//end outputCost
    }//end class
}//end nameSpace
```

The basic function of the program is to gain the number of drawers from the user. Then, gain the wood type and then collect and display a total cost with a description of the order.

Comment: Your code is a wall of text :(

Comment: Edit your question. Select all that code then hit Ctrl-K. Then read [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What difficulty are you having? It's difficult to tell from this what you're asking.

Comment: You say you "have difficulty" but don't describe what the difficulty is. What is it doing wrong? Be specific in your description. And next time, format your code properly before posting, readability is important.

Comment: Yeah, what is the problem with the code? What happens, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What kind of error messages you receive and on which line of code?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, I think you meant to put `deskWoodType = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();`

Comment: Shouldn't your formula be `surchage + (numberOfDrawers * type)`?  Also you don't need `ref` or `out` for most of your methods and should try to avoid them in general.

Comment: There are so many things that don't make sense with this chunk of code that it's unlikely you will get an anwer. You don't state the nature of the problem, the indiscriminate use of ref and out for no reason, unnecessary casts, wrong variable types... It's pretty obvious you are just learning. Try articulating what is wrong first. Just a quick glance tells me you might be referring to getting the wrong cost in the output. You are using int which trims the remainder and then trying to cast it to double. Look into that (among other things)

Comment: I would suggest putting break points in all of the methods and stepping through the code.. also there are better ways of doing this without having to use `ref` params

Comment: I have to second @MethodMan 's suggestion here. Please also see [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some general advice on debugging small programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several people have indicated in the comments, the indiscriminate use of `out` and `ref` is a bad practice.

With that said, your first major problem is that the code as written doesn't compile because you're passing parameters in in the wrong order. For example:

```
CalculateCostMeth(ref numberOfDrawers, ref cost, ref deskWoodType);
```

should actually be

```
CalculateCostMeth(ref deskWoodType, ref numberOfDrawers, ref cost);
```

Even then it won't compile because "cost" is a) the wrong type and b) should be passed with "out" instead of "ref."

Same thing for `OutPutCostMeth` - the order's completely scrambled.

```
OutPutCostMeth(ref deskWoodType, cost, numberOfDrawers);
```

It should actually be

```
OutPutCostMeth(numberOfDrawers, ref deskWoodType, cost);
```

Also, "deskWoodType" shouldn't include the "ref" keyword.

Also, "cost" is a double in the main method and an int in the "OutPutCostMeth" - you can't implicitly convert a double to an int because that may entail data loss. Here are the correct signatures:

```
// New signature - change int cost to double cost and change the return type
private static double CalculateCostMeth(ref string deskWoodType, ref int numberOfDrawers, out double cost)

// Change cost to a double
private static void OutPutCostMeth(int numberOfDrawers, string deskWoodType, double cost)
```

Here are the correct calls:

```
CalculateCostMeth(ref deskWoodType, ref numberOfDrawers, out cost);
OutPutCostMeth(numberOfDrawers, deskWoodType, cost);
```

One final point: make sure you validate user input. Right now entering some random string will make the program crash. I also claimed that I wanted -20 drawers and the program informed me that the store owes me $500. I'd strongly suggest making sure you handle obviously invalid input like that gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also cant get it to display the wood type in " OutPutCost".

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace E03_pt2_3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfDrawers = 0;
            string deskWoodType = "o";
            double cost = 0;
            drawersMeth(out numberOfDrawers);
            woodTypeMeth(out deskWoodType);
            CalculateCostMeth(ref deskWoodType, ref numberOfDrawers, out cost);
            OutPutCostMeth(numberOfDrawers, deskWoodType, cost);
        }//end main
        private static void drawersMeth(out int numberOfDrawers)
        {
            int numOfDrawers;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of desk drawers");
            numOfDrawers = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            numberOfDrawers = numOfDrawers;
        }//end drawersMeth
        private static string woodTypeMeth(out string deskWoodType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the desk wood type. (ex. type mahogany, oak, or pine)");
            deskWoodType = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (deskWoodType)
            {
                case "mahogany":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "m";
                        break;
                    }
                case "oak":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "o";
                        break;
                    }
                case "pine":
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "p";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        deskWoodType = "error";
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return deskWoodType;
        }// end woodTypeMeth
        private static double CalculateCostMeth(ref string deskWoodType,ref int numberOfDrawers, out double cost)
        {
            double pine = 100;
            double oak = 140;
            double other = 180;
            double surchage = 30;
            if (deskWoodType == "p")
                cost = pine + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            else if (deskWoodType == "o")
                cost = oak + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            else
                cost = other + (numberOfDrawers * surchage);
            return cost;
        }// end CalculateCostMeth
        private static void OutPutCostMeth(int numberOfDrawers, string deskWoodType, double cost)
        {
            double totalCost = cost;
            Console.WriteLine("The number of drawers is {0}", numberOfDrawers);
            Console.WriteLine("The wood type you have selected is ", deskWoodType);
            Console.WriteLine("The total cost is {0:c2}", totalCost);
        }//end outputCost
    }//end class
}//end nameSpace
```

This is the corrected version based on your suggestions